# C# Generics Class vs Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I've got a generic repository for updating my EF datacontext as follows (shortened for brevity):

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);
}

public class Repository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
    public TContext DataContext { get; set; }

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, TContext dataContext)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        DataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        DataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (DataContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DataContext.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        return query;
    }
}
```

I want to create an IArchiveOnlyRepository for use with entities that implement my IArchiveable interface. I was hoping that this would work:

```
public interface IArchiveable
{
    bool IsArchived { get; set; }
    DateTime? ArchivedOn { get; set; }
    string ArchivedBy { get; set; }
}

public interface IArchiveOnlyRepository<T> where T : IArchiveable
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Archive(T entity);
    IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);
}

public class ArchiveOnlyRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IArchiveOnlyRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : IArchiveable
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
    public TContext DataContext { get; set; }

    public ArchiveOnlyRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, TContext dataContext)
    {
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        DataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        DataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Archive(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (DataContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            DataContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        entity.IsArchived = true;
        entity.ArchivedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        entity.ArchivedBy = UnitOfWork.UserName;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = DataContext.Set<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
            query = query.Where(filter);

        return query;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the following lines:

```
DataContext.Set<TEntity>()...
```

Generate the following error:

```
The Type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity'
```

How can I define this generic repository to ensure that T is a class that implements IArchiveable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to put your `class` type constraint back on:

```
where TEntity : class, IArchiveable
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to constrain `TEntity` to be `class` (a reference type)

```
public interface IArchiveOnlyRepository<T> where T : IArchiveable, class
...
```

and

```
public class ArchiveOnlyRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IArchiveOnlyRepository<TEntity>
   where TEntity : IArchiveable, class
   where TContext : DbContext
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
where TEntity : IArchiveable
```

to

```
where TEntity : class, IArchiveable
```